# Python, Gmail, Sent Emails Displaying Addresses as Lists of Characters

Tags: python, email, gmail

I wrote an email module that successfully sends emails out, but the recipients see their email addresses displayed as comma-separated lists of characters. In the gmail webmail page, it looks like this: `t, e, s, t, @, g, m, a, i, l, ., c, o, m,`, but with a new line between each letter. In the Thunderbird email client, it looks like this: `t<>, e<>, s<>, t<>, @<>, g<>, m<>, a<>, i<>, l<>, .<>, c<>, o<>, m<>,`. I am using gmail to send these emails. Below is the email module I wrote. Can anyone help me figure out how to make the email addresses display normally to the recipients? Thank you in advance.

```
import smtplib
import ConfigurationManager
from email import encoders
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText


class EmailHandler(object):
    def __init__(self, passed_values):
        self._filename = passed_values.get('filename')
        self._subject = passed_values.get('subject')
        self._from_address = passed_values.get('from_address')
        self._to_addresses = passed_values.get('to_addresses')
        self._email_password = passed_values.get('email_password')
        self._body = passed_values.get('body')

    @property
    def filename(self):
        return self._filename

    @filename.setter
    def filename(self, value):
        self._filename = value

    @property
    def from_address(self):
        return self._from_address

    @from_address.setter
    def from_address(self, value):
        self._from_address = value

    @property
    def to_addresses(self):
        return self._to_addresses

    @to_addresses.setter
    def to_addresses(self, value):
        self._to_addresses = value

    @property
    def body(self):
        return self._body

    @body.setter
    def body(self, value):
        self._body = value

    @property
    def subject(self):
        return self._body

    @body.setter
    def body(self, value):
        self._body = value

    def send_email_with_attachment(self):
        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['From'] = self._from_address
        msg['To'] = ', '.join(self._to_addresses)
        msg['Subject'] = self._subject
        msg.attach(MIMEText(self._body, 'plain'))
        attachment = open (self._filename + '.zip', "rb")
        part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
        part.set_payload(attachment.read())
        encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % self._filename + '.zip')
        msg.attach(part)
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        server.starttls()
        server.login(self._from_address, self._email_password)
        text = msg.as_string()
        server.sendmail(self._from_address, self._to_addresses, text)
        server.quit()
```

Comment: Are you by chance passing `to_addresses` as a string? It should be a list of strings. If you want to pass only one to_address, then it should still be a list with only one element, that is, `['test@example.com']`

Comment: That was it. A very simple change, since the email addresses already started out in a list. I was converting them to a string because I thought it was necessary. Thank you very much! If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Posted as answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're passing `to_addresses` as a string, then it will join every character of the string with the `,`.

In the code you're treating it as a list, so even if you pass only one e-mail address, it needs to be the single string element in a list, like such:

```
['test@example.com']
```